# Making next button behave like submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that has 3 parts.Each part needs to be validated before it can move to next part.

The catch is that there can be only one submit button at the end of it, since I call an external client to process/store the form.

The reason it needs to act like submit button is because it needs to validate the form elements.

The JS works for navigation perfectly, need to find a way to incorporate validation

EDIT: The submit button should work like a submit button but the next button can work as validation button

Code:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Personal Details</h2>

        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title"> Details</h2>
        <input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <input type="text" name="phonenum" placeholder="Phone" required/>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2>More</h2>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
        <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" />
        <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
        <button type="button" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" onclick="callclient()">Submit </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You want it to validate the form like a submit button, but not actually submit the form?

Comment: the submit button should work as submit button and the next button should validate that section

Comment: I think automatic validation only operates on the whole form when it's being submitted. If you want to do validation before that, you should use a validation plugin.

Comment: The automatic validation happens per element as you interact with them. For example you'll see that as soon as you type something that isn't an email into an email input and click away it indicates whether or not it's valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. The code comments should explain it well enough, and it could use additional polishing, but it should get you started:

**HTML**:

```
// I started by separating each form section into its own form
<form class="form-step">
        <fieldset>
        <h2>Personal Details</h2>

        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/>

        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
      </fieldset>
</form>
<form class="form-step">
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title"> Details</h2>
        <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <input type="phone" name="phonenum" placeholder="Phone" required/>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<form class="form-step">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>More</h2>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
        <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" />
        <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" />
        <button type="button" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit">Submit </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var forms = $('form');

    // Whenever a button is clicked
  $(':button').on('click', function(e){

    // Get the current form and the button name
    var $form = $(this).parentsUntil('form');
    var button_name = $(this).attr('name');

    // Validate the form unless going backwards
    if(validate($form) || button_name === 'previous'){

        switch(button_name) {
        case 'next':
            // Next
            next_form();
            break;
        case 'previous':
            // Previous
            prev_form();
            break;
        case 'submit' :
                // Submit
            submit_forms();
            break;
        default:
            // Do nothing
        }

    }else{
        // Form not valid
    }

  });

  // Show next
  function next_form(){
    // Get all visible forms
    var visible_forms = $('form:visible');

    // Get the last form in the array
    var $current_form = $(visible_forms).last();

    // Get the next form
    var $next_form = $current_form.next();

    // Handle visibility of buttons
    $current_form.find(':button').css('visibility','hidden');

    // Show the next form
    $next_form.fadeIn();
  }

  // Show previous
  function prev_form(){
    var visible_forms = $('form:visible');
    var $current_form = $(visible_forms).last();
    var $prev_form = $current_form.prev();
    $prev_form.find(':button').css('visibility','visible');
    $current_form.fadeOut();
  }

  // Submit
  function submit_forms(){

    // All forms are valid
    // Create new form programically that contains all form elements
    // Submit it
    var form_data = forms.find('input:not(:button)').clone();
    var action = '/echo/html/';
    var method = 'POST';
    var $full_form = $('<form/>').attr({
        action: action,
      method: method
    }).append(form_data);

    // Submit the form
    $full_form.appendTo('body').css('display','none').submit();

  }

})

// Validate expects jQuery object
function validate($form){

  // Set valid to true
  var valid = true;

  // Any invalid element will set valid to false
  $.each($form.find('input:not(:button)'), function(index, input){
    // Utilizing HTML5 validation
    if(!input.checkValidity()){
        valid = false;
    }
  })

    return valid;
}
```

[Here's the working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de7k4dgr/8/).